# Setting Current value to EditTextPreference for the first time

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferencefragment

I am developing an android application where I am using Preference Fragment. In that Preference(For Settings) Fragment I have two EditTextPreference to change firstname and last name. What I need is, I want to display the current firstname and lastname to EditTextPreference when I first load the preference fragment so that the user can view their current firstname and lastname, and can change accordingly based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create edittext Preference in xml file at that time you can set default value and summary.

```
<EditTextPreference
             ....
             android:key="key_firstname"
             android:defaultValue="Lincy"
             android:summary="Lincy"/>
```

You can set this for both first name and last name edittext preferences. It will display value when you load preference activity for first time.

Now you can use below code in your preference fragment so that whenever you update edittext preference value, it will always display latest value in summary.

```
EditTextPreference firstname =  (EditTextPreference) findPreference("key_firstname");
firstname .setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("key_firstname","Lincy"));

EditTextPreference lastname=  (EditTextPreference) findPreference("key_lastname");
lastname.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString("key_lastname","Laiju"));
```

To set value of edittext Preference use below code.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
editor.putString("key_firstname","userfirstname"); // You can pass you username value here
editor.putString("key_lastname","userlastname"); // You can pass you username value here
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Hi ,Thank you so much Pooja for the answer.But my problem is i want to set a name which will change dynamically with user login and that also when the user first open the settings page.

Comment: @LincyLaiju Hi, so do you want to set the edittextPreference value programatically? If yes then I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.God bless you.Can I set it in my onResume() or should i do it in onCreate()

Comment: It depends on your requirements. onCreate() called only once. onResume() called every time the activity resumes. @LincyLaiju

Comment: :OK.Have you developed a chat application in android with database in the server part?

Comment: :Thanks for what you did.GoodNight